# Recognising UIWebView file types

Tags: objective-c, pdf, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I wish to detect when a PDF has been clicked and display it in a separate UIWebView. Here's what I have currently:

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType; {
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
    if (fileType != @"PDF") {

        if([urlString rangeOfString:@".pdf"].location == NSNotFound){
            return true;
        } else {
            NSURL *filePath = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
            NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:filePath];
            [pdfViewer loadRequest:requestObj];
            [self.view addSubview:topView];

            fileType = @"PDF";

            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }   
}
```

This works fine. However it does have one Glaring Flaw:

What about "http://www.example.com/ikb3987basd"

How can I recognise a file type without the extension? Is there some sort of data about the file that I can check on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot know the content type of a response before you send the request to the server. At this moment, the client has no way of knowing what hides behind a certain URL. Only when the client receives the server's response can it inspect the Content-Type field in the HTTP header.

I believe what you want to achieve is not possible with the public `UIWebView` API (unless you first start an independent connection to retrieve the header of the URL and check the Content-Type of the response).

Comment: you emphasised "public UIWebView API" in a way that suggests that you know a way, but not with *that* API? Does this mean you have a solution in mind but would require a download of another component?

Comment: No, I don't know a way. But it's clear that `UIWebView` is just a very sparse API over a much more complex framework (WebKit), which is a shame. Apple could clearly expose much more of the workings of `UIWebView` than they do (compare to `WebView` and its numerous delegates on OS X).

Comment: I have mentioned the only solution I can think of. Independently retrieve the header of the URL in question.

Comment: How do I know the response content-type AFTER I sent the request?

Answer (score 0):

Using the special theory of relativity you could prove that it is impossible to know about a file when you dont even have it....:p

And furthermore instead of analyzing the whole URL for 'pdf' i would just look at the file extension which you can get from

[[url absoluteString] pathExtension]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSURLProtocol` sublcass to catch all requests and responses, generated by `UIWebView` (but not (!) `WKWebView`).

In `AppDelegate` in `...didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
[NSURLProtocol registerClass:[MyCustomProtocol class]];
```

This will force `MyCustomProtocol` to handle all network requests.

In implementation of `MyCustomProtocol` something like (code not tested):

```
+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    return YES;
}

+ (NSURLRequest *) canonicalRequestForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request{
    return request;
}

- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request cachedResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse client:(id<NSURLProtocolClient>)client
{
    self = [super initWithRequest:request cachedResponse:cachedResponse client:client];
    if (self) {
         return self;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition))completionHandler
{
    // parse response here for mime-type and content-disposition
    if (shouldDownload) {
        // handle downloading response.URL
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseBecomeDownload);
    } else {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);
    }
    [self.client URLProtocol:self didReceiveResponse:response cacheStoragePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed];

}
```

More details about [NSURLProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlprotocol) you can find in Apple's [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CustomHTTPProtocol/Introduction/Intro.html) and [here](http://oyster.engineering/post/74290088019/getting-creative-with-uiwebview-and-nsurlprotocol)